# How can i skip a specific menu within Nav Walker Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my first question in StackOverflow . I hope you guys can help me on this one .

I'm working on a project that requires specific Wordpress Menu's for specific pages in specific languages .

In example , In English language , I have two type of menus , one for General Audience and one for Companies . So in each language i have two type of menus that i needed to create through Menu Dashboard in Wordpress with Ubermenu Plugin .

A single menu hierarchy is like this :

- Row

  - Column

    - Offers

      - Offer one
      - Offer two
      - Offer Three
  - Column

    - Prices

      - Price Category 1
      - Price Category 2
      - Price Category 3
- Row

  - Column

    - Subscriptions

      - Subscription Package 1
      - Subscription Package 2
      - Subscription Package 3
  - Column

    - Products

      - Product Categorie 1
      - Product Categorie 2

Now I'm trying to create a responsive menu for each of them without using any plugin but with custom walkers . But the problem is that I don't want custom Ubermenu Object Classes to appear in the li's or ul's . In this case ROW and Column .

So whenever the walker sees Row or Column it should pass to a child and add the child as primary menu .

So in this case I wanted to be it like this .

- Offers

  - Offer one
  - Offer two
  - Offer Three
- Prices

  - Price Category 1
  - Price Category 2

    - Price Category 3

Any help on this it would be really appreciated .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Go to Dashboard and check  Appearence->menu

Comment: @Samyappa thanks for your reply.  thats easy one . Already created the menu with that . I need to know a custom walker code to achieve my goal . Thanks anyway